# Advice for MySQL database modeling

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm in need of some advice for creating a database model which holds data for multiple users. I will try to be as specific as possible. Please excuse me if this is too broad or inappropriate.

I'm creating a web application where users can sign up and add data about their sportsteams. After registration the user has to be able to add members to a table and add achievements to another table.

Right now i have 4 tables in all. `members_table` holds all members of a sportsteam. `achievements_table` holds all achievements. `member_has_achievement` holds the relation between a member and a achievement, and acts as the unique identifier.

And lastly i have a `login_table`.

This table has multiple columns:
`loginid`
`username`
`password`
`email`

My initial thought was to create a relation table between `login_table`and the `members_table`. So that one user can have multiple members, and these members can have multiple achievements.

But I'm not sure this is the best way to do this.
I build this model for a single user app, but I'm having trouble scaling it up.

Any advice for how I could model this differently?

Comment: What's the difference between user and member?

Comment: Also you don't need `member_has_achievement` as long as you put the unique identifier in achievements_table (like an unique id for the achievement and the member has an unique id, so you can just insert this unique id in achievements_table).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I think he needs member_has_achievement, looks like the achievements_table stores all available achievements, and the member_has_achievement is saying which ones the member has. So reasonable to have it (it's many-to-many relationship).

Comment: The user is the actual person that adds info to the database. He/she acts as the admin for a given sportsteam. The members are entities of the sportsteam. For example user adds member A to the database. And the adds achievement B to member A.

Comment: Daniel Gruszczyk is right!

Comment: You can find some helpful designs on the link i provided. And oh! you can thank me later.:D

Comment: I marked your solution as helpful, isn't that thank you enough? :D But thanks, I'm relatively new to database modeling. Did some at the university, but thats 5 semesters ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems good for now. Imagine you have multiple users, stored in your users table.
Now if a user can add a member, all you need is in a members_table, add your user_id as a foreign key:

```
-----------------
| Members_table |
-----------------
| ID : PK       |
| User_ID : FK  |
| Name          |
| anything_else |
-----------------

-----------------
| User          |
-----------------
| ID : PK       |
| email         |
| login         |
| password      |
-----------------
```

I don't see a reason why this wouldn't scale up. You can see by User_ID which member was added by which user etc...  Basically this is one-to-many relationship : one user can have many members, but a member belongs to one user only, if I understand you correctly :)

User table here would be your login_table btw :)

Comment: Yes - I just was thinking if this was the best way. But as you pointed out it can actually work :)

Answer (score 1):

[I found this link useful for database designs for beginners.](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm)

Here, assumming that you are designing a database for students as users:

[image]

and for simpler model:

[image]